# Install package having dependency from another source using nuget.exe

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I need to install a nuget package from the one source (repository that i am maintaining) that has dependency on the another package from another source (basically from microsoft official package source) using nuget.exe i.e

```
nuget.exe install Package_name -Source ""
```

Comment: I know one way is to provide semicolon separated multiple sources while providing source in the command but it is taking too much time. Is there any other solution available.

Comment: I also tried with the help of config file i.e -ConfigFile Nuget.config but it is also taking too much time. Is there any parameter that i am missing due to which this is happening.